# React native - get current month and set it to Graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Im currently working on my project on a screen that will present Incomes/Outcomes of a business.
Im trying to present the data in graph, using the dependency of "react-native-chart-kit"

My goal is to display the incomes of the current month(October) and the previous 3 months before(jul,aug,sep) and 2 months ahead(nov,dec)
But,right now im stuck at presenting the months in the graph.
I was able to get the current month and display it, but i cant figure out the formula to display the previous and ahead months.

Code:

```
const d = new Date();
  const v = d.getMonth() + 1;
  console.log("V => ", v);

  const data = {
  
    labels: ["Jul","Aug","Sep",v,"Nov","Dec"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [1300, 45, 28, 80, 99, 43],
        color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(134, 65, 244, ${opacity})`, // optional
        strokeWidth: 2, // optional
      },
    ],
    legend: ["Incomes - Quarter displayed"], // optional
  };
```

How can i fetch the months into the labels array?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following :

```
var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; //To get the Current Month
                
labels: [this.checkMonthName(month-3), this.checkMonthName(month-2), this.checkMonthName(month-1), 
         this.checkMonthName(month), this.checkMonthName(month+1), this.checkMonthName(month+2)]
```

Then identify this function **checkMonthName** to return month name from its number :

```
  checkMonthName =(month)=>{

    var monthName ;

      if(month == 1)  monthName = "January"
      else if(month == 2) monthName = "February" 
      else if(month == 3) monthName = "March"
      else if(month == 4) monthName = "April"
      else if(month == 5) monthName = "May"
      else if(month == 6) monthName = "June"
      else if(month == 7) monthName = "July"
      else if(month == 8) monthName = "August"
      else if(month == 9) monthName = "September"
      else if(month == 10) monthName = "October"
      else if(month == 11) monthName = "November"
      else if(month == 12) monthName = "December"

      return monthName;
  }
```

> **- You should handle if the current month is earlier, because month-3 would be negative and this will affect your result**
>
> Or
>
> **- if the current month is a late month like December so month+1 will be equal 13**

May be there're simpler ways, but This is what I have in my mind right now.

Comment: Actually im stuck at what you described.. the negative or the result 13.. cant figure out what to do

Comment: If the current month was January for example, Would you display incomes of the previous months of last year?

Comment: No, it meant to be only for the current year, thats something else i would need to deal with

Comment: Great, Check if the current month is in range from 4 to 10 so it'll be ok. But if not, print a message to the user.

Comment: im not sure how and where to do it

Comment: After this line :
 var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; if(month>=4 && month<=10) {
labels: [this.checkMonthName(month-3), this.checkMonthName(month-2), this.checkMonthName(month-1), this.checkMonthName(month), this.checkMonthName(month+1), this.checkMonthName(month+2)]
}
else
alert("Not available");

Comment: I cant put labels array outside the data object

Comment: var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; 
if(month>=4 && month<=10) { 
 //execute what inside data object
}
else 
alert("Not available");